# Getting bower and gulpjs to work nicely together?

Tags: backbone.js, gulp

Using gulpjs and bower, Id like to start with the bower.json file to call on what package dependencies I want (ideally start the build with html 5 boilerplate, then backbone). Since the whole point of using gulp is for easy project management I would like to understand how to auto insert the scripts in to my project (pulling from the bower_components dir) and add the path to my head tags, I assume this is a responsibility gulp should be handling, in the link below I am under the impression grunt does provide this functionality, so if grunt can gulp should be able to.

This tut seems to cover everything I am looking for, except it is using gruntjs with the plugin "grunt-bowercopy" http://simonsmith.io/managing-bower-components-with-grunt/

So does anyone know how to get gulp and bower to play nicely. It would be cool to download the html 5 boilerplate, then for my javascript include backbone/jquery as well as some css like fontawesome and such with one command `bower update`, and have it insert the script tags in my header, and pull the main files I need into my project (this would kill a lot of tedious work). I assume grunt does handle this specifically with the "grunt-bowercopy" plugin, so essentially I am looking for a plugin "gulp-bowercopy" or something that provides this?

I still have a lot to learn about gulp/grunt and how to really leverage them, but this seems like an awesome tool to have.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> essentially I am looking for a plugin "gulp-bowercopy" or something that provides this

You should then consider looking into either:

- [gulp-bower](https://github.com/zont/gulp-bower)
- or [gulp-bower-files](https://github.com/ck86/gulp-bower-files)

as they likely provide the same functionality as grunt-bowercopy.

Comment: I just saw https://www.npmjs.org/package/gulp-bower-files and read the description and yeah this seems to be what I am looking for.

Comment: I had gulp-bower installed but didnt see what purpose it served, trying to read over it again I came across, gulp-bower-files and that seems to make sense on what its purpose is. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can just use wiredep directly like the [gulp Yeoman generator](https://github.com/yeoman/generator-gulp-webapp) does. Here's a code sample from the gulpfile.js.

```
var wiredep = require('wiredep').stream;

gulp.task('wiredep', function () {
    gulp.src('app/styles/*.scss')
        .pipe(wiredep({
            directory: 'app/bower_components',
            ignorePath: 'app/bower_components/'
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('app/styles'));

    gulp.src('app/*.html')
        .pipe(wiredep({
            directory: 'app/bower_components',
            ignorePath: 'app/'
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('app'));
});
```